# How can I change image color using JColorChooser in Java

Tags: java, jcolorchooser

how can I change image color using jcolorchooser like this
in java 
Image 1
[image: Image 1]
 
to
Image 2
[image: Image 2]

```
File input = new File("dprocessing.jpg");
image = ImageIO.read(input);
width = image.getWidth();
height = image.getHeight();

for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
    Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
    int red = (int)(c.getRed() * 0.299);
    int green = (int)(c.getGreen() * 0.587);
    int blue = (int)(c.getBlue() *0.114);
    Color newColor = new Color(red+green+blue,red+green+blue,red+green+blue);

    image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
  }
}

File ouptut = new File("new_Image.jpg");
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", ouptut);
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: sorry sir i am new here i can't upload code it is saying you need atleast 10 reputation

Comment: you can just copy and paste it into your question

Comment: thank you sir code is added

Comment: what is happening right now? what is the output you're getting with this code?

Comment: i am getting this output [link](http://prntscr.com/fpl4n6)

Comment: please add that to your question

Comment: Why that sum on new Color (red+green+blu, ...) etc. ? You are not using Color (int rgb) constructor, you are using Color(int r, int g, int b) constructor, so you should calculate your components and give them separately to the constructor ...

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by changing it to this:

```
File input = new File("dprocessing.jpg");
     image = ImageIO.read(input);
     width = image.getWidth();
     height = image.getHeight();

     for(int i=0; i<height; i++){

        for(int j=0; j<width; j++){

           Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
           int red = (int)(c.getRed() * 0.299);
           int green = (int)(c.getGreen() * 0.587);
           int blue = (int)(c.getBlue() *0.114);
           if(c.getRed()>200&&c.getGreen()>200&&c.getBlue()<100){ //this is to make sure that the pixel is some form of yellow. if it is yellow, change it to purple. if it isn't keep the color the same
                 Color newColor = new Color(red,green,blue); //before you were making every field the sum of all 3 colors, I don't know why
                 image.setRGB(j,i,newColor.getRGB());
           }
           else{
                 image.setRGB(j,i,c.getRGB());
           }

        }
     }

     File ouptut = new File("new_Image.jpg");
     ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", ouptut);
```

let me know if this works for you

Comment: Nope this is also giving the same result

Comment: Really? I think it should work, or at the very least output a different image than the first one. Did you recompile the project?

Comment: what is the output this time?